# Getting oAuth2 Vimeo access token in cURL

Tags: curl, vimeo, vimeo-api

I get this problem when I try to get my access token for Vimeo

```
      % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   439  100   139  100   300    161    349 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--   391{
    "error": "invalid_client",
    "error_description": "A valid client ID must be provided along with any request made to Vimeo's API"
}
```

MY CODE:

```
curl -X POST -d "client_id=<myClientID>;client_secret=<secretID>;grant_type=authorization_code; response_type=code;redirect_uri=<redirectURL>" https://api.vimeo.com/oauth/access_token
```

The response I want is:

```
{
 "access_token": "TOKEN",
 "token_type": "Bearer"
}
```

And yes my client_id IS correct!
Can someone please help me, I`m trying to get a token for Vimeo API

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To fix this request, you need to use ampersands instead of semicolons in the -d parameter.

But this won't solve your problem. This request returns a full HTML page that the end user interacts with to authorize your app. If you just need an access token for yourself you should manually create one in your app settings.